# object instance's properties crushed by another instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, instance

I am kind of new to node.js/javascript, and come from C# world : probably my problem is about transposing C# habits to javascript...

I created a small node.js app to reproduce the problem I run into.
In the app, two 'Kid' are created. Each of them graps a balloon, and makes it bounce with more or less power (parameter). When the balloon stops boucing, we get a log from an event fired..

The problem I have is that **the first instanciated kid seems to be crushed by the last one**. The crush seems to happen on a call to the 'bounce' function.

Here is the log sequence i am expecting:

> 1. Mike arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....
> 2. Elia arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....
> 3. Ensure that Mike's name is Mike...
> 4. Ensure that Elia's name is Elia...
> 5. Mike just got a balloon and wrote his/her name on it !
> 6. Mike makes the balloon bounce (force 10) !
> 7. Elia just got a balloon and wrote his/her name on it !
> 8. Elia makes the balloon bounce (force 4) !
> 9. Elia's balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is Elia.
>
> 10.Mike's balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is Mike.

Here is the log sequence i get:

> 1. Mike arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....
> 2. Elia arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....
> 3. Ensure that Mike's name is Mike...
> 4. Ensure that Elia's name is Elia...
> 5. **Elia just got a balloon and wrote his/her name on it** !
> 6. **Elia makes the balloon bounce (force 10)** !
> 7. Elia just got a balloon and wrote his/her name on it !
> 8. Elia makes the balloon bounce (force 4) !
> 9. Elia's balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is Elia.
>
> 10.**Elia's balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is Elia**.

The three files composing the app.

app.js

```
const Kid = require('./kid.js');

var mike = new Kid('Mike');
var elia = new Kid('Elia');

console.log(`Ensure that Mike's name is ${mike.name}...`);
console.log(`Ensure that Elia's name is ${elia.name}...`);

mike.bounce(10);
elia.bounce(4);
```

kid.js

```
const Balloon = require('./balloon.js');
var self;

function Kid(name){
    self=this;
    this.name=name;

    console.log(`${this.name} arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....`);
}

Kid.prototype.bounce = function(force1To10) {
    var balloon = new Balloon(self.name); 
    balloon.bounce(force1To10);    
    balloon.on('balloonStopped',(kidnameWrittenOnIt)=>{
        console.log(`${self.name}'s balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is ${kidnameWrittenOnIt}.`);
    });
};

module.exports=Kid;
```

balloon.js

```
const timers = require("timers");
var inherits = require('util').inherits;  
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var self;

function Balloon(kidName) {
    self = this;
    this.kidName = kidName;

    this.bounce = function(kidsPower1To10){
        console.log(`${self.kidName} makes the balloon bounce (force ${kidsPower1To10}) !`);
        timers.setTimeout(() => {
            self.emit('balloonStopped',self.kidName);
        }, kidsPower1To10*1000); 
    }

    console.log(`${this.kidName} just got a balloon and wrote his/her name on it !`);
}

inherits(Balloon, EventEmitter);
module.exports = Balloon;
```

To execute:

```
node app.js
```

Thanks by advance for any useful information !

Comment: If you're coming from C# you may find it easier to use Classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: thanks @MattHolland, wasn't aware of that feature in ECMAScript2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the problem is in the `bounce` method. You reference a global `self` variable which will reference the second person. So if you call `bounce` on the first person, it will still reference the second in there.

The solution is to use `this` directly instead of `self`, or to define `self` in each method:

```
function Kid(name){
    this.name=name;

    console.log(`${this.name} arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....`);
}

Kid.prototype.bounce = function(force1To10) {
    var balloon = new Balloon(this.name); 
    balloon.bounce(force1To10);
    balloon.on('balloonStopped',(kidnameWrittenOnIt)=>{
        console.log(`${this.name}'s balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is ${kidnameWrittenOnIt}.`);
    });
};
```

Now you still have to take care that when you reference the `bounce` method, you make sure `this` is correctly bound. This will be the case when you do call `mike.bounce(10)` or `elia.bounce(2)`, but there are pitfalls when you start assigning the `bounce` method to another variable and call that other variable. In that case `this` will be undefined.

#### Class notation

You can also code the above with the `class` syntax:

```
class Kid {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name=name;
        console.log(`${this.name} arrived in the garden. The kid wants to play with a balloon....`);
    } 
    bounce(force1To10) {
        var balloon = new Balloon(this.name); 
        balloon.bounce(force1To10);
        balloon.on('balloonStopped',(kidnameWrittenOnIt)=>{
            console.log(`${this.name}'s balloon has stopped bouncing... The name written on it is ${kidnameWrittenOnIt}.`);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ! I replaced the 'self' variable by this in kid.js and balloon.js and indeed it worked. I was mistaken by considering each file as a class (as i would in C#); your explanation totally makes sense.